# c# hiding method on derived class and using Attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, radix, derived, custom-attribute

I have sample object model as below.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class CandidateApiForMenuItem : Attribute
{
    public CandidateApiForMenuItem(string caption)
    {
        this.Caption = caption;
    }

    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class FormDataElementBase
{
    public FormDataElementBase()
    {

    }

    [CandidateApiForMenuItem("Add PanelGroup")]
    public void AddPanelGroup()
    {
        ///...
    }

    [CandidateApiForMenuItem("Add BoxGroup")]
    public void AddBoxGroup()
    {
        ///...
    }


    [CandidateApiForMenuItem("Remove")]
    public void Remove()
    {
        ///...
    }

    public void GenerateGroupPopupMenuItems()
    {
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in this.GetType().GetMethods())
        {
            if (methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CandidateApiForMenuItem)) != null)
            {
                // This is true both for FormDataElementBase and all derived
                // but I want to hide Remove method inside MainGroup class
                // However it is displayed again
            };
        };
    }
}

public class BoxGroup : FormDataElementBase
{

}

public class PanelGroup : FormDataElementBase
{

}

public class MainGroup : FormDataElementBase
{
    private void Remove()
    {
    }
}
```

When user right click, application will display PopupMenu (GenerateGroupPopupMenuItems method). Items of menu will be based on methods who has CandidateApiForMenuItem  declared. However, there are derived class (MainGroup) where some methods (f.e: Remove) should not be displayed. What I did, inside MainGroup declared Remove method as private. However, it is displayed again.

Could you pls let me know what I am doing worng here?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `new public void Remove() => base.Remove();`?

Comment: This condition display that also. If(methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CandidateApiForMenuItem)) != null)...

Comment: You did not 'change' Remove to private, you added another one. See your Warnings window.

Comment: @Tim What if in your GenerateGroupPopupMenuItems method, you filter on more than just the presence of the attribute?  You gave yourself a Caption property in the attribute; what if you check that property for a special string value (defined as a constant) that signals removal?  That avoids using virtual methods.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `this.GetType().GetMethods()` without parameters returns only public instance (i.e. non-static) methods. So `MainGroup.Remove` won't be returned by this call.

If you make `MainGroup.Remove` public, `this.GetType().GetMethods()` will return both methods - for base class and for derived one. Not what you want, I suppose.

If you make `FormDataElementBase.Remove` virtual and `MainGroup.Remove` override, GetMethods will return only one `Remove` method (with `DeclaringType==typeof(MainGroup)`) - this is better.

And finally, I'd suggest to introduce one more attribute, say, `CandidateApiIgnore`. If we mark an overridden method with this attribute and modify in the following way `GenerateGroupPopupMenuItems` method, the stuff should work:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class CandidateApiIgnore : Attribute
{
    public CandidateApiIgnore() { }
}

public class FormDataElementBase
{
///...
    [CandidateApiForMenuItem("Remove")]
    public virtual void Remove()
    {
        ///...
    }

    public void GenerateGroupPopupMenuItems()
    {
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in this.GetType().GetMethods())
        {
            if (methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CandidateApiForMenuItem)) != null &&
                methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CandidateApiIgnore)) == null)
            {
                // If a method is overridden and marked with
                // CandidateApiIgnore attribute in a derived
                // class, it won't be processed here.
            };
        };
}

public class MainGroup : FormDataElementBase
{
    [CandidateApiIgnore]
    public override void Remove()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a new attribute is a good idea, however I am looking for reflection and without marking virtual on the base class. Thanks.